# GraphQL query with JWT from async getIdTokenClaims() in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

**Updated**

As @shahroon-farooqi demonstrated below this pattern is well documented by urql [here](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/advanced/authentication/) including rationale for the [wonka library dependency](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/architecture/#the-wonka-library).

Updated working demo [on GitHub](https://github.com/whitebrick/gatsby-starter-typescript-auth0-hasura).

---

I'm new to React and still having trouble working out how the async awaits fit together with respect to hooks.

I have a minimal Gatsby/React starter project (my full code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/whitebrick/gatsby-starter-typescript-auth0-hasura)) that I have pieced together from other examples that:

1. Signs-in and gets a JWT from Auth0 and saves it in local storage; and then
2. Includes that JWT in a GraphQL request to fetch and display a list of Organizations.

When this is processed in the browser as 2 separate page loads (ie I first click sign-in and I'm then redirected to the view the list of Organizations page) it works as expected. But once I'm already signed-in and I click the browser refresh button on the list of Organizations page, I can see that GraphQL fetch fails because it is called before the client has had a chance to load the JWT into the header. The JWT is successfully loaded a split second later but I need this to happen before the GraphQL fetch is attempted.

The auth and client is passed as a wrapper:

```
// gatsby-browser.js    
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={process.env.GATSBY_AUTH0_DOMAIN}
      redirectUri={process.env.GATSBY_AUTH0_REDIRECT_URI}
      ...
    >
      <AuthApolloProvider>{element}</AuthApolloProvider>
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
}
```

And the client is set up with the JWT like this:

```
// src/api/AuthApolloProvider.tsx
const setupClient = (_token) => {
  return createClient({
    url: process.env.GATSBY_HASURA_GRAPHQL_URL,
    fetchOptions: () => {
      return {
        headers: {
          authorization: _token ? `Bearer ${_token}` : "",
        },
      };
    },
  });
};
const AuthApolloProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently, isAuthenticated, getIdTokenClaims } =
    useAuth0();
  const [token, setToken] = useState("");
  const [client, setClient] = useState(setupClient(token));
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        const tokenClaims = await getIdTokenClaims();
        setToken(tokenClaims.__raw);
      }
    })();
  }, [isAuthenticated, getAccessTokenSilently]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setClient(setupClient(token));
  }, [token]);
  return <Provider value={client}>{children}</Provider>;
};
```

I then have this contoller to get the list of Organizations:

```
// src/controllers/Organizations.ts
import { useQuery } from "urql"

const GET_ORGANIZATIONS = `
query get_organizations {
  organizations {
    name
    label
  }
}
`
export const useOrganizations = () => {
  const [{ data, fetching }] = useQuery({ query: GET_ORGANIZATIONS })
  return {
    organizations: data?.organizations,
    loading: fetching,
  }
}
```

And finally my list of Organizations component:

```
// src/components/Organizations/OrganizationList.tsx
import { useOrganizations } from "../../controllers/Organizations";

const OrganizationList = () => {
  const { organizations, loading } = useOrganizations();
  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        organizations.map((organization: OrganizationItemType) => (
          <OrganizationItem
            organization={organization}
            key={organization.name}
          />
        ))
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

So as I understand it, I don't want to make the `useOrganizations()` call in the component until the async method inside `AuthApolloProvider` has completed and successfully loaded the JWT into the client.

Because I'm new to React and I've pieced this together from other examples I'm not sure how to approach this - any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your ApolloProvider. You will need to add Wonka, as urql utilises the Wonka library.

```
import React from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { pipe, map, mergeMap, fromPromise, fromValue } from "wonka";
import {
  createClient,
  Provider,
  dedupExchange,
  cacheExchange,
  fetchExchange,
  Exchange,
  Operation,
} from "urql";

interface AuthApolloProviderProps {
  children: React.ReactChildren;
}

const fetchOptionsExchange =
  (fn: any): Exchange =>
  ({ forward }) =>
  (ops$) => {
    return pipe(
      ops$,
      mergeMap((operation: Operation) => {
        const result = fn(operation.context.fetchOptions);
        return pipe(
          (typeof result.then === "function"
            ? fromPromise(result)
            : fromValue(result)) as any,
          map((fetchOptions: RequestInit | (() => RequestInit)) => ({
            ...operation,
            context: { ...operation.context, fetchOptions },
          }))
        );
      }),
      forward
    );
  };

const AuthApolloProvider = ({ children }: AuthApolloProviderProps) => {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently, getIdTokenClaims } = useAuth0();

  const url = process.env.GATSBY_HASURA_GRAPHQL_URL;
  let client = null;

  if (url) {
    client = createClient({
      url: url,
      exchanges: [
        dedupExchange,
        cacheExchange,
        fetchOptionsExchange(async (fetchOptions: any) => {
          await getAccessTokenSilently({
            audience: process.env.GATSBY_AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
            scope: "openid profile email offline_access",
            ignoreCache: true,
          });

          const tokenClaims = await getIdTokenClaims();
          const token = tokenClaims?.__raw;

          return Promise.resolve({
            ...fetchOptions,
            headers: {
              Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
            },
          });
        }),
        fetchExchange,
      ],
    });
  } else {
    throw new Error("url not define");
  }

  return <Provider value={client}>{children}</Provider>;
};

export default AuthApolloProvider;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (token.length === 0) return
    setClient(setupClient(token))
  }, [token])
```

You probably don't want to setClient/setupClient when token is empty? Code inside useEffect gets executed at least 2 time.

1. Component mount (at this point token is still empty)
2. When token value gets changed

Comment: That is true I do not want to setup with an empty token - I added the improvement thanks but when I refresh the page the GraphQL request is still failing because it is getting called before the client has setup with the token.

Comment: Is there some way I can make useOrganizations() wait until the component has mounted (and the internal async method completed)?